# Distribution of Product of Normal and Poisson?

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, approximation

Suppose that X is distributed Poisson with a known rate and Y is a normal distributed with a know mean and variance.  My goal is to approximate the distribution Z where P(Z) = P(X) * P(Y), where Z is a non-negative integer.  I could get a good approximation by sampling, but I'd really like to have a fast solution, ideally closed-form.

Comment: Do you have an idea of likely values for the parameters of each distribution? Specifically, if the rate parameter of the Poisson distribution is large then you could use a Normal approximation and the product of two Normal distributions appears to be well studied.

Comment: (i) Did you mean to take the product of a pdf and a pmf there where you say P(X)*P(Y)? That doesn't seem to match your title which implies a product of random variables. (ii) You don't state what the bivariate distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is, only the margins.

Comment: To put it in slightly different terms what already pointed out by @Glen_b, Poisson is a discrete distribution, where your variable X assumes integer values 0...n, but a normal distribution is a continuous one, where your variable Y takes values -infinity to +infinity.

Answer (score 2):

There is one book dedicated to the problem of products of random variables:
[http://www.amazon.com/Products-Random-Variables-Applications-Arithmetical/dp/0824754026/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1383564424&sr=1-1&keywords=product+of+random+variables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824754026)

Maybe you can find it in a library. (Or search google scholar  with the author names)

There is a connection between products of independent random variables and the Mellin transform, see the paper: "[Some Applications of the Mellin Transform in Statistics](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-19/issue-3/Some-Applications-of-the-Mellin-Transform-in-Statistics/10.1214/aoms/1177730201.full)" by Benjamin Epstein, which is on JSTOR. There is a [Wikipedia article on the Mellin Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#In_probability_theory), and search google scholar for "Mellin transform product of random variables" gives some relevant papers.